# 16.04 update : several issues

Tags: grub2, upgrade, suspend, 16.04, hibernate

I recently upgraded from ubuntu 15.10 to ubuntu 16.04 (and at the same time from gnome 3.16 to gnome 3.18 I think) and it all went pretty bad. The x server didn't want to start anymore. After some research I learned that it was a conflict between plymouth and nvidia, so I uninstalled everything related to Nvidia, and uninstalled plymouth.
Another issue was that I had to edit one grub boot option from "ro" to "rw".

With these 2 things, I was able to start my computer. Since then, I had 1 other issue, which seems to be common but I still haven't found a solution : when I suspend / hibernate my computer (I still don't get the difference), and then turn it on again, the screen remains black with only th "power" LED turned on.
Also, I've read that changing permanently grub's boot option from ro to rw wasn't a good solution, and that I should search for the root of the problem.

Being at my early days of using Ubuntu, I could really benefit from someone's help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Well how can I fix both of these issue : how could I get the "suspend" to work correctly, and how could I fix permanently the grub "ro" problem in a way that isn't bad for my sstem. Sorry if I wasn't clear